# Add Incrementing to class

Tags: php, css

Can someone explain me how to add an incrementing to class?

I would like to have:

```
div class="slide1"
div class="slide2"
div class="slide3"
...
```

Here's the code:

```
<?php if( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ): ?>
    <ul class="slides">

        <?php while( have_rows('afbeeldingen') ): the_row(); 
        // vars
        $image = get_sub_field('afbeelding');
        ?>
        <li class="slide<?php echo $i; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />
        </li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the increment operator...

```
    <?php $i = 0; /* define $i ... */ while( have_rows('afbeeldingen') ): the_row(); 
    // vars
    $image = get_sub_field('afbeelding');
    ?>
    <li class="slide<?php echo $++i; // increment it! ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />
    </li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not incrementing your counter.

```
<?php if( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ): ?>
    <ul class="slides">

        <?php while( have_rows('afbeeldingen') ): the_row(); 
        // vars
        $image = get_sub_field('afbeelding');
        ?>
        <li class="slide<?php echo $i++; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />
        </li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define $i outside the while loop, something like `$i = 0;`. Then inside the loop increment $i after each loop iteration with something like `$i++`.